# Is TouchUpOutside the correct control event for events outside of an element?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm three days new into swift development, even Xcode for that matter. I've created a UIView called EncounterMenu that appears over my app when i click the menu button. My goal is to have the EncounterMenu UIView close when I do anything outside of it.. This is what I have so far

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //create a button that spans the width & height of the encounter menu
    let btnEncounterMenu = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    btnEncounterMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, EncounterMenu.frame.width, EncounterMenu.frame.height)
    //(this is whats not working) If user clicks outside of button, call function "closeEncounter:"
    btnEncounterMenu.addTarget(self, action: "closeEncounter:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpOutside)
    //Add the button to the EncounterMenu
    EncounterMenu.addSubview(btnEncounterMenu)
}

func closeEncounter(sender: UIButton!) {
    EncounterMenu.hidden = true;

}
```

I tried changing it to TouchUpInside and it worked when i clicked inside the EncounterMenu UIView, so I figured it should be as easy as TouchUpOutside?

Any direction to what I'm doing wrong or how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touch up outside will not work because you need to be pressing on the menu first, then drag your finger outside for that to register.  instead, the easiest option for you to do is to create  a button that is the entire size of your view, and on that buttons touch down event,  fire off close menu.  just make sure that this big button is at the very back of the view, and everything else is built on top of it.

Comment: Wow okay, I didn't realise touchUpOutside worked that way. Wish there was a prettier solution for this, but that sounds like it will work just fine! I'll confirm as answer when I get a chance

Comment: There are other ways to go about doing it, like the touch end event on the view itself,  but you said you were 3 days in, and I did not want to throw anything complex your way

Comment: if you have a more professional approach, by all means go for it. I've been programming for about 8 years now :), just getting used to the mac & xcode with swift

Comment: Looking back at my code,  in the viewcontroller class, I would override the touchesEnded function, and in there dismiss the overlay if it was active